# Building a Customizable Report

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, crystal-reports, report

i want to build a payroll report that user can select or deselect columns as he wanted. for example for each employee user can select check boxes that represent each column in a list  like - Nic, Net salary , Nopay day , etc in any combination.i think all columns are returned in the SP and only shows selected columns.(i saw this on another software and want appy it on our software) 
Can you please give me some idea how to do it..
im using report component in visual studio also can use crystal reports.

Answer (score 0):

We use a javascript control called [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) for this type of this at our company, It has a column chooser, required/optional columns, allows columns to be hidden by default if you want, and can do paging and sorting.

Comment: sorry im using winforms can u give me equal component in winforms?

Comment: I have only used one, http://www.infragistics.com/products/windows-forms/grid/ which has more than just grid